# Static Relative Files Not Found with Express `sendFile()` and Custom Root

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to serve a static folder, when using dynamic routes, by using `res.sendFile()` in ExpressJS:

```
res.sendFile('index.html', { root : path.join(__dirname, 'myStaticContentFolder') });
```

The file `.../myStaticContentFolder/index.html`, indeed gets served - hence: the `root` field correctly adjusts the path to it.
However, all the files within that folder, with paths relative to `index.html` are not found.
They are searched relative to the URL root instead of the `root` field path.

Note that the folder is properly served if I use:

```
app.use('/foo/', express.static(__dirname + '/myStaticContentFolder'));
```